# DataTable Search Expression

Tags: c#

I have this challenge of fetching result from DataTable.search. The Expression I am using is not getting result. Is there a limit to the length of 'Expression' that can be used? Is it wrong to use all columns in the DataTable?

I am trying to compare rows in two DataTables that have same definitions. Using the first one, I'm trying to fetch rows that are not in the second one and saving them in a 'ResultDataTable' so as to update the DataBase of the first DataTable with the save values.

```
private DataTable ExtractRecord(DataTable localTable, DataTable importedTable)
{
    DataTable returnTable = new DataTable(importedTable.TableName);

    DataRow[] returnedDataRows;
    Dictionary<int, string> DicColumnDataType = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < importedTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        DicColumnDataType.Add(i, importedTable.Columns[i].DataType.Name);
        myDataColumn newCol = new myDataColumn(importedTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString(), importedTable.Columns[i].DataType);
        returnTable.Columns.Add(newCol);
        returnTable.AcceptChanges();
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in importedTable.Rows)
    {
        object[] RowValues = row.ItemArray;

        string Expression = "WHERE " + @" ";

        int ColCount = localTable.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < ColCount; i++)
        {
            switch (DicColumnDataType[i])
            {
                case "Int32":
                    Expression = Expression.Remove(Expression.Length - 1, 1);
                    Expression += importedTable.Columns[i].ColumnName + " Like '%" + RowValues[i] + "%' AND " + " ";
                    break;
                case "String":
                    Expression = Expression.Remove(Expression.Length - 1, 1);
                    Expression += importedTable.Columns[i].ColumnName + " Like '%" + RowValues[i] + "%' AND " + " ";
                    break;
                case "Boolean":
                    Expression = Expression.Remove(Expression.Length - 1, 1);
                    Expression += importedTable.Columns[i].ColumnName + " Like '% " + RowValues[i] + "%' AND " + " ";
                    break;
                case "DateTime":
                    Expression = Expression.Remove(Expression.Length - 1, 1);
                    Expression += importedTable.Columns[i].ColumnName + " Like '%#" + RowValues[i] + "#%' AND " + " ";
                    break;

            }
        }

        Expression = Expression.Substring(0, Expression.Length - 6);

        try
        {
            returnedDataRows = localTable.Select(Expression);

            if (1 > returnedDataRows.Length)
            {
                returnTable.ImportRow(row);
                returnedDataRows = null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }

    returnTable.AcceptChanges();
    return returnTable;
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) example, it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: Here is an example of expression returned by the iteration...     "WHERE Nme Like '%Anayo Faith Onyeali%' AND Mnth Like '%December 2017%' AND Dte Like '%#01/15/2018 12:00:00 AM#%' AND Pl Like '%80%' AND Vs Like '%0%' AND Hr Like '%15%' AND Rv Like '%4%' AND Bs Like '%2%' AND Rmk Like '%%' AND Aux Like '% False%' AND Late Like '% True%'"